# Difference between onClick() and onChange() for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="book_folder" onchange="makeRadioButtons()">Create New Book</input>

<input type="radio" name="group" value="book_chapter" onchange="makeCheckBoxes()">Create New Chapter</input>
```

I was using the above code and when I clicked the second radio button, I thought I should get two events, one from the button that got unchecked and other from the button that got checked, because logically speaking, both buttons got their state changed, and I have bound the `onchange()` event not the `onclick()` event. But as it seems I only get one event from the button that just got checked. Is this a desired behaviour in HTML? How can I get an event from the button if it got unchecked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this to get the desired behavior:-

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName('group');
var i = ele.length;
for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (ele[j].checked) { //index has to be j.
        alert('radio '+j+' checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('radio '+j+' unchecked');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: meaning i shud call this function from every onchange event?

Comment: i just found out....if i use `ele.length;` it works fine...and it tells what radio button was checked and unchecked...the only prblm is that we are forced to traverse all the buttons in the group.

Comment: Please check my updated answer & see if you still get the "`null`" value.

Comment: nope still nt working....the prblm is in `ele.count()` ...this might be a browser issue? im using chrome!

Comment: Okay, that may be the reason, as I haven't checked with Chrome yet. Still sounds great to know that you got your solution nicely!

Answer (score 7):

Both of these check boxes make up a single HTML element, whose name is `group`. That's why you are getting only one event here.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Md8fj/3/) is a demo example which demonstrates how to iterate through each of the separate checkbox and access their values.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But if i un-group them...they all can be selected at the same time..i want to select only one button at a time!

Comment: @Salman then you might want to use jQuery to attach events to the radios using their id attribute. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erKURITA/ZYR6N/2/

Comment: thank you so much...so infact the solution is to differentiate and perform action depending on their "value" attribute!!

Answer (score 5):

To browser, N radio buttons with one name are just one control. Because when it wants to send the post data (or get data) back to the server, it simply uses the `name` attribute as the key of the parameter and the value of the currently selected radio button which has that name attribute as the value of the sent parameter. That's why you should name attribute to group radios together. So, onchange shouldn't logically occur 10 times for 10 radios. From the point of the browser, the value of the `group` control changed from `book_folder` to `book_chapter`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to save vale of the current checked radio button, so when event is fired, you will have old checked button value save, and you could then use that, because at one time only once radio button will be checked. after that you could save the updated radio button checked value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function( ){
      $( "input[name='group']" ).on(
        {
          'change' : function( )
                     {
                       $.each( $( "input[name='group']" ),
                               function( )
                               {
                                 var ObjectId, ObjectValue;

                                 if( $(this).is(':checked') )
                                 {
                                   /*Checked radio button OBJECT */

                                   console.log(this);                      /* Jquery "this" Object */
                                   ObjectId    = $(this).attr( 'id' );     /* Id of above Jquery object */
                                   ObjectValue = $(this).val(  );          /* Value of above Jquery object */
                                 }
                                  else
                                 {
                                   /* UnChecked radio button OBJECT */
                                   console.log(this);                      /* Jquery "this" Object */
                                   ObjectId    = $(this).attr( 'id' );     /* Id of above Jquery object */
                                   ObjectValue = $(this).val(  );          /* Value of above Jquery object */
                                 }
                               }
                             );
                     }
        }
     );
  });
```